# calling dialog box from a button mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm new using jquery, and developing for web, and i have this doubt, i want to create a modal dialog when i push an html button. i use the next code for the button

```
 <input type="submit" value="Siguiente"/>
```

In the modal dialog, i want to push some information that i get frm the form, and i want to create 2 buttons, one to redirect to another page and the other keeps in the same page, something like yes or no buttons.

```
public ActionResult EntradaPedidos()
         {

             List<SelectListItem> divisiones = new List<SelectListItem>();
             List<Pedidos> misPedidos = miConexion.Division(username, password);
             foreach (var pedido in misPedidos)
             {
                 divisiones.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = pedido.nombreDivision, Value = pedido.division });
             }
             ViewData["divisiones"] = new SelectList(divisiones, "Value", "Text", "Confeccion");

             //Ejemplo para llevar informacion a un label
             Pedidos miPedido = new Pedidos();
             miPedido.clave1 = "Funciona";
             miPedido.numPedido = "234";

             ViewData["FechaInicio"] = "";
             ViewData["codigoCliente"] = "";
             ViewData["ddListaPrecios"] = new SelectList(new[] { "(Selecciona)" });
             ViewData["ddListaVendedores"] = new SelectList(new[] { "(Selecciona)" });
             ViewData["listPrecios"] = "";
             ViewData["ddCiudad"] = new SelectList(new[] { "(Selecciona)" });
             ViewData["ddPuntosEntrega"] = new SelectList(new[] { "(Selecciona)" });

             return View(miPedido);
         }



[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EntradaPedidos(FormCollection formulario) {

        Pedidos miPedido = new Pedidos();
        miPedido.division = Request.Form["division"];
        miPedido.fechaPedido = Request.Form["FechaInicio"];
        miPedido.codigoCliente = Request.Form["codigoCliente"];
        miPedido.codListaPrecios = Request.Form["tbListaPrecios"];
        miPedido.codVendedor = Request.Form["ddListaVendedores"];
        miPedido.codPuntoEntrega = Request.Form["ddPuntosEntrega"];


        return RedirectToAction("EntradaPedidosProducto");
}
```

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language but please consider revising your post to include an actual question. Right now it's not very clear what it is exactly that you're asking.

Comment: yes, isn't my first languaje, i try to edit my question, hope its ok now. that is what i want to do

Comment: i'm reading something of jquery ui, but i can't find how i call the modal dialog, how can i push the data, or how i create the buttons on the modal dialog.

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc  - it shows how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI modal popup and load the content of it using an ajax request to a partial view which contains your form.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Include jQuery UI plugin reference in your page /View

```
 $('#yourForm').submit(function (e) {
       var url = "yourcontroller/EntradaPedidos"        
       var dialog = $("#dialog");
        if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
             dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
           }
           dialog.load(
                    url,
                    {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        dialog.dialog({
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                dialog.remove();
                            },
                            modal: true,                               
                             width: 460
                        });
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
```

Another point to mention is that try to avoid using ViewData and start using a ViewModel for that.

Comment: i create my form using
<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>

how i assign a name?

Comment: no problem. If your form has an id, use that, or just use the form without #. or you can give an id or class to submit button and bind to its click event

Comment: what i do whit this? is for getting the data of the post metod of my view?    yourcontroller/actiontorenderpartialview?id=id_to_get_data

Comment: what you mean by post method of your view ? views will be always froma get method. post method you use in your controller when you submit the form. Can you add your controller methods to the question ?

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa : Use that action name then. I updated the answer

Comment: thanks man, i'm going to start trying different things, with your code, y push the html of the view, on the dialog. i'm going to search how i take the value of those elements and push into my dialog (just the value y entered on the page)